# what is outgoing and incoming policy in the router setting?

Tags: wireless-networking, mac

What is incoming/outgoing policy in the router setting? and is there any difference between incoming/outgoing policy and incoming/outgoing direction?

When I want to configure my router to allow a specific device(s) to connect the Internet trough my router using its MAC address, is it allowing outgoing or incoming?

what is the difference between source MAC and destination MAC address?

Comment: -1 "Finally what is the difference between source MAC and destination MAC address?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MAC (Media Access Control) address is a value associated with the network interface of the device (PC, mobile phone, tablet, IP Camera,etc). On Windows using `ipconfig /all` the MAC appears as  *physical address*.

Each device have a unique MAC configured from factory that is unique on the world. So there is no chance of two devices with the same MAC.

When two devices (for example two PCs) have to communicate on a LAN, they use a protocol as IP but to access the *LAN* cable or the *wifi* they need to use the MAC address. IP provides a way to make a relation of MAC address and IP, it's called ARP.

On Windows, go to Command Prompt use the command `arp -a` and you can see a table that relates IP to MAC.

For example, suppose we have a PC called **A** with IP `192.168.2.1` and MAC `15-c5` and a PC called **B** with IP `192.168.2.2` and MAC `2b-f7`.

If *A* sends data to *B*, then A takes that data and put it inside an **IP Packet** with *Source IP address* 192.168.2.1 and *IP destination address* 192.168.2.2. The IP packet is like an envelope that encapsulates the data.

To access the *LAN*, the **IP Packet** must be put inside an **Ethernet frame**. The Ethernet frame will use *source MAC address* `15-c5` and *destination MAC address* `2b-f7`. The ethernet frame is an external envelope that makes it easy to move frames on the LAN.

It's typical that home routers have a menu that let block source MAC address in a way that they can't connect to the wifi or to internet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. so the destination MAC address is always my MAC router address, whatever the direction is. and i understand that any device use my router to access the Internet is the outgoing direction. so what is incoming one?

Comment: A router has at least two interfaces, so it depends of the *point of view*, it means on which interface you are. If you are on the LAN interface, *incoming* frames come from the PCs on LAN and *outgoing* frames are going from router to PCs.

Comment: re the uniqueness in mac addresses, according to the textbooks, yes. But see this answer,     http://superuser.com/questions/268006/are-mac-addresses-unique-when-coming-out-of-the-factory     see the 16 million figure in one answer, and the cases of reuse mentioned in another answer. so 'reasonably unique' would be more accurate. This sentence of yours "So there is no chance of two devices with the same MAC."  <-- is not correct.